# Leaflet.VectorGrid throws error Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use [Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#vectorgrid-slicer), but I am getting error:

`Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object`.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-river-16579?file=/src/VectorGrid.js)

**VectorGrid.js**

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import L from "leaflet";
import geojsonvt from "geojson-vt";
import "leaflet.vectorgrid";
import { featureCollection, feature } from "@turf/helpers";
    
export default function VectorGrid({ assets }) {
  const { layerContainer, map } = useLeafletContext();
    
  const geoJsons = assets
    .filter((asset) => asset.mapPolygon)
    .map((asset) => feature(asset.mapPolygon.geometry));
    
    const slicerInput = featureCollection(geoJsons);
    
  console.log(slicerInput);
    
  const data = geojsonvt(slicerInput);
    
  const vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(data, {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: {
        fillColor: "transparent",
        color: "blue",
        weight: 0.5,
      },
    },
    maxZoom: 22,
    indexMaxZoom: 5, // max zoom in the initial tile index
    interactive: true,
  });
    
  const container = layerContainer || map;
    
  useEffect(() => {
    container.addLayer(vectorGrid);
    return () => {
      container.removeLayer(vectorGrid);
    };
  }, [container, vectorGrid]);
    
  return null;
}
```

**temp_data.js**

```js
export const dat = [
{
  assetid: 1,
  id: 1,
  mapPolygon: {
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
          [-104.98948, 39.64244],
          [-104.98953, 39.64244],
          [-104.98953, 39.64236],
          [-104.98918, 39.64236],
          [-104.98918, 39.64247],
          [-104.98948, 39.64247],
          [-104.98948, 39.64244],
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
}, {
  assetid: 3,
  id: 3,
  mapPolygon: {
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
          [-104.98793, 39.6444],
          [-104.98816, 39.64439],
          [-104.98816, 39.64438],
          [-104.98825, 39.64437],
          [-104.98825, 39.64432],
          [-104.98826, 39.64431],
          [-104.98826, 39.64429],
          [-104.98828, 39.64429],
          [-104.98827, 39.64422],
          [-104.988, 39.64422],
          [-104.98799, 39.64429],
          [-104.98793, 39.64429],
          [-104.98793, 39.6444],
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
}]
```

Comment: This is one of those instances where the error message is telling you what's wrong. Do read https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html and https://geojson.org/ and use https://geojsonlint.com/ .

Comment: I didn't know about geojsonlint.com tool, thanks